# error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'overloaded-function' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Tags: c++

This was my original code:

```
#include <iostream>

void printArrayValues(int x, int y)
{
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    std::cout << y << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int myArray[2];

    std::cout << "Please enter what you want the first element in 'myArray' to be: ";
    std::cin >> myArray[0] >> std::endl;
    std::cout << "Please enter what you want the second element in 'myArray' to be: ";
    std::cin >> myArray[1] >> std::endl;

    printArrayValues(myArray[0], myArray[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

I looked up my error and it said it was because I didn't `#include <string>`. I was confused by this because there are no strings being declared, but I went ahead and `#include`ed it anyways. It appeared to have fixed it, but then when I came back, the same error was back. Here is my new code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <string>

void printArrayValues(int x, int y)
{
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    std::cout << y << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int myArray[2];

    std::cout << "Please enter what you want the first element in 'myArray' to be: ";
    std::cin >> myArray[0] >> std::endl;
    std::cout << "Please enter what you want the second element in 'myArray' to be: ";
    std::cin >> myArray[1] >> std::endl;

    printArrayValues(myArray[0], myArray[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

The errors are still showing up, so it's still not fixed and I'm not sure what to do. Can someone show me how to fix it and explain why that specific fix works? Thanks!

Comment: `endl` is for use on output streams, not input streams.

Comment: What is the actual error message you're getting? There's nothing in the code you posted that would cause the error in the title.

Comment: Also, it would be good to know at which line in code the error appears. You can [edit] your question to add this info, even now when your question is answered.

Answer (score 5):

```
std::cin >> myArray[0] >> std::endl;
```

is not correct. `std::endl` is meant to work only with output streams. Example:

```
std::cout << myArray[0] << std::endl;
```

If you want to skip everything up to the newline character, use [`std::istream::ignore()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) <sup>1</sup>.

```
std::cin >> myArray[0];
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

However, in your case, you don't need it, as `operator>>` ignores leading whitespace by default (unless you use `std::noskipws`), including line breaks. You can simply use:

```
std::cout << "Please enter what you want the first element in 'myArray' to be: ";
std::cin >> myArray[0];
std::cout << "Please enter what you want the second element in 'myArray' to be: ";
std::cin >> myArray[1];
```

---

<sup>1</sup>: If you decide to use `std::cin.ignore()`, add

```
#include <limits>
```

to get the definition of `std::numeric_limits`.